# Chat bot-Can I display html content using node.js in Microsoft bot framework & bot builder

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework

I'm developing a chatbot on azure using node.js. It's a data visualization bot which generates chart in html format using d3 library and display to user. 
It seems that Microsoft bot builder doesn't support html format. But I have looked through this link: 
https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/07/html-not-supported-web-chat/
It says that there is a way to enable html content: 
"If HTML rendering in Web Chat is a critical feature for your applications, you can clone or fork a copy of the Web Chat source code from GitHub, and enable it (on your own custom Web Chat client)."
I tried to clone the file and changed  ‘html : false’ to ‘html : true’. But it's not working.

Can anyone tell me what I can do? Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Also, I'm having problem linking d3 library tgt with chat bot. Cos d3 needs to draw chart on a html web page, but a chat bot doesn't have a web page for d3 to draw chart on.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to clone the Web Chat repo? also, There's a fun example of vega charts rendered as images in a bot here: https://github.com/nwhitmont/botbuilder-vega

Comment: Thanks Eric! That helps a lot. I will give it a try.

Comment: Do you know any example that creates chart for bot with vega? Like in the code you showed me, the chart is already created in json format (if I'm not wrong?) and stored in local directory: ./charts/county-unemployment.vg.json. But i'm not sure how to create this. I looked through vega tutorial they all envolve html page. I'm not sure how to do that in a bot service which doesn't have a html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what data you are attempting to visualize, you might be able to use a service like Google Image Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_playground

Using this service, with the following code:

```
// attach the card to the reply message
var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(createHeroCard(session));
session.send(msg);


function createHeroCard(session) {
            return new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title('Months with Numbers Bar Chart')
                .subtitle('Using a Chart as Image service...')
                .text('Build and connect intelligent bots that have charts rendered as images.')
                .images([
                    builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=250x150&chd=s:Monkeys&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul')
                ])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework/', 'Get Started')
                ]);
        }
```

Produces this hero card:

[image: hero card with chart image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. My only concern is that google chart api can't support complicated chart generation in the future. But for now it's all good. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey sorry for bothering you. Just realised this google chart api a deprecated version. I checked the new version but the code are all imbedded in html file. Is it possible to implement the new google api without html?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems like you could use getImageURI() server side.  And render the base64 encoded image in the card.  Here is an example of base64 content: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-SendAttachment#attaching-the-image-inline